# Disable Variable Product Price When Select a Variable of Woocommerce Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to display price when user select a variable of product one time,but woocommerce shows price twice.
if prices between variables different replace variable price to product price and dosnt show price of a selected variable ,if not shows price difference also in product price.
some body help me